# Oracle SQL : search column that starts with digits

Tags: sql, string, oracle, digits

I'd like to find all the rows which column value begins with a digit.

Its works well with this request :

```
    WHERE trim(u_ods_val3.ods_itn_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI)    IS NOT NULL
  AND (SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)='0'
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='1'
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='2 '
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='3'
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='4'
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='5'
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='6'
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='7'
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='8'
  OR SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1)  ='9')
```

But it is too long.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use [LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm), it is exactly for this

Answer (score 23):

[Regexp_like](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501) would be in handy and much shorter

```
where regexp_like(trim(col_name), '^[0-9]')
```

or using character class

```
where regexp_like(trim(col_name), '^[[:digit:]]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `in` :

```
WHERE trim(u_ods_val3.ods_itn_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI)    IS NOT NULL
  AND SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1) in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
```

Answer (score 1):

`BETWEEN` is all you need! (`NOT NULL` is implicit in this case!)

```
WHERE SUBSTR(u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI,0,1) between '0' and '9'
```

If you have an index on that column, and don't mind the little dirtyness of this solution, you can even speed it up:

```
WHERE u_ods_val3.ODS_ITN_PHRSBMO.NO_ART_TECH_OI between '0' and '9~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
```

This assumes that NO_ART_TECH_OI doesn't contain characters with ascii code > 126.